# ImageMagick add watermark proportionally

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, overlay, watermark

I want to add a watermark `logo.png` to the `nature.jpg` with ImageMagick, I use the following commands:

```
magick nature.jpg logo.png -gravity southeast -geometry +10+10 -composite nature-wm.jpg
convert nature.jpg -resize 50% nature-50%.jpg
magick nature-50%.jpg logo.png -gravity southeast -geometry +10+10 -composite nature-50%-wm.jpg
```

As you can see, the watermark is smaller when adding it to an image which has large width and height, but this is not what I expected, what I expected is that the watermark can always occupy a fixed percentage of the main image, anyone know how to do this?

logo image

[image: logo image]

original image
[image: original image]

Original image with watermark added
[image: origin image add watermark]

50% width and height of the original image(`nature-50%.jpg`)
[image: 50% of original image]

`nature-50%.jpg` with watermark added(the logo in `nature-50%.jpg` looks bigger than in the original image)
[image: 50% if original image add watermark]

#### Update

I want to rotate the watermark, but my approach is not what I expected, it's weird

```
magick nature.jpg -set option:logowidth "%[fx:int(w*0.25)]" \
\( logo.png -resize "%[logowidth]x" -rotate 45 \)                       \
-gravity southeast -geometry +10+10 -composite result.jpg
```

[image: rotate watermark]

Comment: I'm not at a machine to test, but you probably need to set  `-background none` and `-virtual-pixel background` before rotating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do that by loading the background, calculating the width of the logo relative to that (here I used 0.25 as my factor), then loading the logo and resizing before compositing:

```
magick background.jpg -set option:logowidth "%[fx:int(w*0.25)]" \
   \( logo.png -resize "%[logowidth]x" \)                       \
   -gravity southeast -geometry +10+10 -composite result.jpg
```

---

Regarding changing the transparency, per your comment, you could make the logo 30% opaque like this:

```
magick background.jpg -set option:logowidth "%[fx:int(w*0.25)]" \( logo.png -resize "%[logowidth]x" -channel A -fx "u*0.3" \) -gravity southeast -geometry +10+10 -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you so much. BTW, how can I set the transparency of the `logo.png` ?

Comment: @Willis I have added a way of setting the alpha layer.

Comment: Thank you. I also tried to rotate the logo, but it's weird(I've updated it to my question)

Comment: can I do resize while keeping the original logo file e.g kept it in memory not save it to disk

Comment: @Salem I'm not sure what you mean - please just ask a new question with all the details - questions (and answers) are free.

Comment: OK I solve it from other question, the command works